# What quickly templates are available

Tags: application-development, quickly

How to get list of official an unofficial quickly templates. I googled it ,but did'nt got any satisfactory result .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The templates that come with quickly are:

- ubuntu-application (python+GTK3 desktop app)
- ubuntu-cli (python command-line app)
- ubuntu-flash-game (wraps an existing .swf file in a Gtk window with WebKit)

The [quickly-unity-lens-template](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quickly-unity-lens-template) [image: Install quickly-unity-lens-template] package contains:

- unity-lens (a python+Singlet lens for Unity)

In addition to these stable templates, there are some new ones that are still in the works and should only be used for testing purposes right now:

- [Quickly community templates](https://launchpad.net/quickly-community-templates)

If you are participating in the [Ubuntu App Showdown](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/), you should use the ubuntu-application template.

Comment: but now that the quickly requirement is gone, so is the ubuntu-application template requirement, right?

Comment: Yes, not the topic of the question, but that's correct.